# Keep content inside div when zooming in and out on a browser

Tags: html, css

When i zoom in and out on my website, the navigation bar and my "Open Touch" text seems to go out of the div and float down and for my navigation bar, it seems to disappear word by word when i zoom in. I've been trying to fix this for the past 2days and researching on this website and nothing seems to work.
My code and codepen will be available as well

How can I keep the "Open Touch" Text from overlapping the navigation bar?

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xqLLeJ

html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:700" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet"> 

             <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="magicstyle.css">


        <body>
            <!-- Section for Jobs Popup -->
                 <div id="job-popup">
                <div class="x-div"><img class="x-icon1" id="fadeX" src="web%20x%20icon%20white.png"></div>
                    <div id="job-content">
                    <h1 id="jobWords">Test</h1>

                    </div>

                </div>
            <!-- Section for Contact Popup -->
            <div id="contact-popup">
            <div class="x-div2"><img class="x-icon2" id="fadeX2" src="web%20x%20icon%20white.png"></div>
            <div id="contact-content">

                <h1 id="contactWords">Test</h1>

                </div>

            </div>

            <!-- Section for Press Popu -->
             <div id="press-popup">
            <div class="x-div3"><img class="x-icon3" id="fadeX3" src="web%20x%20icon%20white.png"></div>
            <div id="press-content">

                <h1 id="pressWords">Test</h1>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div id="legal-popup">
            <div class="x-div4"><img class="x-icon4" id="fadeX4" src="web%20x%20icon%20white.png"></div>
            <div id="legal-content">

                <h1 id="legalWords">Test</h1>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div id="support-popup">
            <div class="x-div5"><img class="x-icon5" id="fadeX5" src="web%20x%20icon%20white.png"></div>
            <div id="support-content">

                <h1 id="supportWords">Test</h1>

                </div>

            </div>



                <div id="top-bar">
                        <a class="burger-nav"></a>
                    <div id="nav-menu">
                    <span id="job">Jobs</span>
                    <span id="contact">Contact</span>
                    <span id="press">Press</span>
                    <span id="legal">Legal</span>
                    <span id="support">Support</span>

                    </div>


                </div>
            <div id="container">


                <div id="name-div">
                <h1 id="name">Open Touch</h1>
                </div>
                <ul class="bubbles">

            <li id="firstCircle"></li>
            <li id="secondCircle"></li>
            <li id="thirdCircle"></li>
            <li id="fourthCircle"></li>
            <li id="fifthCircle"></li>
            <li id="sixthCircle"></li>



            </ul>



            </div>

        </body>



    </head>




</html>
```

Any help is appreciated,
Thank You

Comment: Have you heard of responsive design?

Comment: is it media queries ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take out `overflow: hidden` from

```
#nav-menu {
    width: 50%;
    height: 70%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 101;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    left: 15%;
    top: 20%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help :D And I am using jquery to make when the person opens one of the tabs and clicks "x" img its suppose to close but it is not closing for some reason. codeine.io/anon/GWvXQL